# How to pass javascript function in php

Tags: javascript, php

1 I wrote this code and it works fine without php condition.

```
<select sorted class='form-control required' onchange="saveDetailData(<?php echo $detail->id ?>,$(this).val(),'batchNo' )">
 <option value='0'>Select Batch</option>

 <?php if(!empty($batchDetail) && $userInfo[0]->isManual == 1)
  {
  foreach ($batchDetail as $cl19)
      {
      ?>
 <option value='<?php echo $cl19->batchNo ?>' <?php if ($cl19->batchNo == $detail->batchNo) { echo 'selected=selected';} ?>><?php echo date('d-M-Y', strtotime(date('Y-m-d', strtotime($cl19->inwardDate)))).  ' - ' . $cl19->batchNo .' ( '.$cl19->stockQty.' )'?></option>
         <?php
       }
   }
 ?>                                              
</select>
```

2 And this code under PHP condition does not work.

```
<?php
  if($userInfo[0]->isManual == 1){echo "
    <select sorted class='form-control required' onchange='saveDetailData($detail->id,$(this).val(),'batchNo' )'>
   <option value='0'>Select Batch</option>
 ";}
?>

  <?php if(!empty($batchDetail) && $userInfo[0]->isManual == 1)
    {
   foreach ($batchDetail as $cl19)
      {
  ?>
   <option value='$cl19->batchNo' <?php if ($cl19->batchNo == $detail->batchNo) { echo 'selected=selected';} ?>><?php echo date('d-M-Y', strtotime(date('Y-m-d', strtotime($cl19->inwardDate)))).  ' - ' . $cl19->batchNo .' ( '.$cl19->stockQty.' )'?></option>
      <?php
       }
    }
?>
<?php
 if($userInfo[0]->isManual == 1){echo "
  </select>
    ";}
 ?>
```

3 This is what I get output of not working code:

```
<select sorted="" class="form-control required" onchange="saveDetailData(244,$(this).val()," batchno'="" )'="">

    <option value="0">Select Batch</option>                                                                                                               
    <option value="t51">25-Oct-2018 - t51 ( 5 )</option>                                                                                                                       
    <option value="t58">25-Dec-2018 - t58 ( 410 )</option>

</select>
```

4 This is output of working code:

```
<select sorted="" class="form-control required" onchange="saveDetailData(244,$(this).val(),'batchNo' )">

    <option value="0">Select Batch</option>                                                                                                               
    <option value="t51">25-Oct-2018 - t51 ( 5 )</option>                                                                                                                       
    <option value="t58">25-Dec-2018 - t58 ( 410 )</option>
```

the only issue is it is not going into the function `onchange` when i put php condition on No.2 check No. 3 for its output.

all I want to do is put this code in my php condition of `if($userInfo[0]->isManual == 1)`

I used this and solved:

```
if($userInfo[0]->isManual == 1){echo '
<select sorted class="form-control required" onchange="saveDetailData('.$detail->id.',$(this).val(),\'batchNo\' )">
   <option value="0">Select Batch</option>
     ';}
?>
```

Comment: If I had to guess I'd say your issue stems from your usage of `'` in `onchange='saveDetailData($detail->id,$(this).val(),'batchNo' )'`.  You're using `'` as the delimiter for the on change handler, but also around the batchNo literal.

Comment: Also a side note; given that you are doing an inline event handler, `onchange="saveDetailData(244,$(this).val(),'batchNo')"` could really be `onchange="saveDetailData(244,this.value,'batchNo')"`.  You don't really need jQuery to get the value there.

Comment: @Taplar i cant put "" onchange because its already on echo check no. 2

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    <select sorted class='form-control required' <?php if ($userInfo[0]->isManual == 1) { ?> onchange="saveDetailData('<?php echo $detail->id ?>', $(this).val(), 'batchNo')" <?php } ?>>
```

Comment: i need whole code under `$userInfo[0]->isManual == 1` condition